# Toolbar :com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

Hi I am working with Toolbar to replace the Actionbar.

I tried with my .xml file.

In this file I tried with the Toolbar as root layout.
I included the support-v7-appcompat library.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/music_actionbar_display_home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/music_actionbar_backbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/home_back"           
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/music_actionbar_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/home_square_logo"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/music_actionbar_language"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/music_actionbar_display_home"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
```

What I did wrong ?

Comment: This exception is thrown when you try to run your app? Could you please put the full stacktrace?

Comment: @Shyish This is rendering exception. Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Comment: Sometimes the layout editor is not working properly, could you try to run the app to see what happens?

Comment: @Shyish Ok. I will check and let you know. :)